# Best place to initialise random generator

Tags: c++, performance

In my program I use a random number generator quite a lot. I believe the general rule is that you should define things as close to the place where they're "called", but does this also hold true for random number generators?

For example, in my code I have the choice between:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rng(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(-2147483647, 2147483646);

lots of code

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        variable x = uni(rng);
    }
```

Or

```
lots of code

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 rng(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(-2147483647, 2147483646); 
        variable x = uni(rng);
    }
```

I would say the first method is faster, but I've gotten a bit confused due to reading many threads in which it is stated to always place everything as close to the place where it's called.

Comment: This has nothing to do with performance. This is simply about correctness. The second piece of code doesn't actually run the RNG (more than once), it just plays back new seeds taken from the `random_device`. Use the first code, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, it's *much better* to create the RNG outside your loop:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rng(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(-2147483647, 2147483646);

for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    variable x = uni(rng);
}
```

The reason for this has little to do with performance (although it will likely perform better, too). The reason is to do with correctness:

You're initialising a new random sequence each time through the loop, and reading just one value. Instead, you should be initialising the sequence just once, and consuming many values from it. Initialise outside the loop, and consume within the loop.

---

On the performance side, reading from a `std::random_device` is much slower than taking the next value from a PRNG such as `std::mt19937`. Doing this just once, outside the loop, will save a lot of time. Further, the `std::mt19937` PRNG has a large state (624 integers). It generates this initial state from the value passed to its constructor. Again, doing this just once will give you a performance boost.

Of course, initialising outside the loop has the advantage of also being the correct usage model for the standard RNGs.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is, when you located your random generator definings on top of your code, they will become global and they will be defined automatically when you first hit the "Run" button. If you are using those variables in more than one place, probably it would be the best idea. But if you are not, you don't need it. Because in some scenarios, they might not even called. Anyway, this suggestion is for class or method usages.

However, from what I see, you are going to use that number in a for loop, which will cause your computer to run below code 1000 times.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rng(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(-2147483647, 2147483646);
```

That is unnecessary, and useless. I beleive your first code will work better on performance side.